# convergence of a fibonacci-like sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I posted a question earlier on finding a formula for the sequence

$$t_1, t_2, t_1+t_2, t_1+2t_2,....$$

[This is the question I posted earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231423/creating-a-formula-for-a-n-for-a-fibonacci-like-sequence/3231436#3231436)

I want to show that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n} \rightarrow \phi$

The relationship is $T_n = A_nF_{n-2} +B_n F_{n_1}$

Where $A_1=1, A_2=0, A_{n+2} = A_{n+1}+A_{n}$ and

$B_1=0, B_2=1, B_{n+2} = B_{n+1}+B_{n}$

Since $A_n=F_{n-2}$ and $B_n = F_{n-1}$ then

$T_n = t_1 F_{n-2}+t_nF_{n-1}$

I'm wondering if this proof will work. I know that this sequence is like Fibonacci and it converges to the golden ratio...

suppose as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $F_{n+1}/F_n$  converges to a limit $L$.

Then: $L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1 +\frac {1}{L}$

So I solve $L=1+\frac{1}{L} \implies L=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$

We take the positive root so the answer is $\phi$

The reason i am confused is because this is for convergence $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ but my sequence isn't exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [linear recurrence theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Roots_of_the_characteristic_polynomial), as characteristic polynomial of the sequence is $x^2 - x - 1$ and it's roots are $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, we have $t_n = A \left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n + B \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$ where $A$ and $B$ can be found from $t_1$ and $t_2$. If $A \neq 0$ then  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{t_{n + 1}}{t_n} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{B}{A}(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{1 + \sqrt{5}})^n\right] / \left[1 + \frac{B}{A}(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{1 + \sqrt{5}})^n\right] = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ (because $|\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{1 + \sqrt{5}}| < 1$), otherwise it is $\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

And if $A = 0$ then $t_1$ and $t_2$ have different signs - so if they are both positive, $A \neq 0$.

Comment: sorry i'm just a little confused, how did you get the equation for $t_n$ I looked at the link you provided and I'm still confused.

Comment: Sorry, I for some reason was certain there is closed form solution on this page. Link refers to Wikipedia now, which definitely includes such formula.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. also, when you say you can find $A$ and $B$ from $t_1$ and $t_2$ what exactly does that mean? just pick n as 1 and 2 and substitute? also why does the limit hold for $A\neq 0$ ?

Comment: For $A$ and $B$ does my definition for those sequences work? can I just state those values for $A_n$ and $B_n$ instead of solving for them by using $t_1, t_2$?

Comment: Yes, you just pick two values for $n$ and solver linear system. I edited post to be add one extra transition for limit if $A \neq 0$. $A$ and $B$ in general form are different from your $A_n$ and $B_n$. And of course you can define the sequence by setting $A$ and $B$ instead of $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: thank you so much! final question: based on the sequence I have, is it enough to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}}=\phi$ since I have a shifted fibonacci sequence?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what exactly is your shifted Fibonacci sequence. If you have sequence of form $t_n = a F_n + b F_{n - 1}$, then $\lim t_{n + 1} / t_n = \phi$ unless $a \phi + b = 0$. If you have sequence of the form $t_n = a F_{n + k}$ (with $k$ not necessary positive) then $\lim t_{n + 1} / t_n = \phi$, as sequence of this fractions is just $F_{n + 1} / F_n$ shifted by $k$.

Comment: thanks again. and you just used a clever trick to divide both numerator and denominator of the limit by $A(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$ right? so that it's easier to calculate the limit

Comment: Actually I used it only for prove. To find limit (in a way that's simpler to perform but harder to justify) I just noted that $|\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}| > |\frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2}|$, so $(\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2})^n \gg (\frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2})^n$ and we can ignore the second terms in numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is practically a Fibonacci recurrence,  with starting 
values different from $F_1=1,\; F_2=1$, like it is for Lucas sequence .
Clearly, if your $T_1 , T_2$ happens to be equal to  two consecutive F's, then you just have
a shifted Fibonacci Sequence.

Also in your case we have the matrix relation
$$
\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,k + 2} }  \cr    {T_{\,k + 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,k + 1} }  \cr    {T_{\,k} }  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {\matrix{   {T_{n + 2} }  \cr    {T_{\,n + 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,n} \left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,2} }  \cr    {T_{\,1} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$

The  matrix elevated to $n$ can also be written as
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,n}  = \left( {\matrix{
   {F_{\,n + 1} } & {F_{\,n} }  \cr 
   {F_{\,n} } & {F_{\,n - 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
therefore
$$
{{T_{n + 2} } \over {T_{\,n + 1} }} = {{T_{\,2} F_{\,n + 1}  + T_{\,1} F_{\,n} } \over {T_{\,2} F_{\,n}  + T_{\,1} F_{\,n - 1} }}
 = {{\left( {T_{\,2}  + T_{\,1} } \right)F_{\,n}  + T_{\,2} F_{\,n - 1} } \over {T_{\,2} F_{\,n}  + T_{\,1} F_{\,n - 1} }}
 = {{\left( {T_{\,2}  + T_{\,1} } \right)F_{\,n} /F_{\,n - 1}  + T_{\,2} } \over {T_{\,2} F_{\,n} /F_{\,n - 1}  + T_{\,1} }}
$$
and the limit follows easily

Also refer to the para. "Closed-form expression" in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)

*--- answer to your comment  ---*

The vectorial representation is just a translation of the recursive identity (plus an obvious one)
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  T_{\,n + 2}  = T_{\,n + 1}  + T_{\,n}  \hfill \cr 
  T_{\,n + 1}  = T_{\,n + 1}  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 
\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,n + 2} }  \cr    {T_{\,n + 1} }  \cr  } } \right)
 = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr  } } \right)
\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,n + 1} }  \cr    {T_{\,n} }  \cr  } } \right)
$$
which has the advantage that multiple recursion steps are translated into matrix multiplication (power)
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,n + 2} }  \cr    {T_{\,n + 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,n + 1} }  \cr    {T_{\,n} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,n} }  \cr    {T_{\,n - 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) =  \cdots  =   \cr   &  = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr  1 & 0 \cr
 } } \right)^{\,n} \left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,2} }  \cr    {T_{\,1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$

Since the Fibonacci N. obey to the same recurrence
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {\matrix{   {F_{\,n + 2} }  \cr    {F_{\,n + 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,n} \left( {\matrix{   {F_{\,2} }  \cr    {F_{\,1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,n} \left( {\matrix{   1  \cr    1  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,n}  = \left( {\matrix{   {F_{\,n + 1} } & {F_{\,n} }  \cr    {F_{\,n} } & {F_{\,n - 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {\matrix{   {T_{n + 2} }  \cr    {T_{\,n + 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1  \cr    1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)^{\,n} \left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,2} }  \cr    {T_{\,1} }  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{   {F_{\,n + 1} } & {F_{\,n} }  \cr    {F_{\,n} } & {F_{\,n - 1} }  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{   {T_{\,2} }  \cr    {T_{\,1} }  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  T_{\,n + 2}  = T_{\,2} F_{\,n + 1}  + T_{\,1} F_{\,n}  = T_{\,2} F_{\,n}  + T_{\,2} F_{\,n - 1}  + T_{\,1} F_{\,n}  \hfill \cr 
  T_{\,n + 1}  = T_{\,2} F_{\,n}  + T_{\,1} F_{\,n - 1}  \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

Comment: I'm confused about the matric relation because I don't know why you decided to raise it to the nth power. and  the last line you have with $\frac{T_{n+2}}{T_{n+1}}$, where are you getting that equality from? i'm just wondering which matrices you are multiplying to get that

Comment: also am i looking for the pell numbers in the lucas sequence?

Comment: @user130306: I added some "slow motion" clarifications: hope they are "enlighting"